# Not enough arguments for mixin: SASS

Tags: sass

I am trying to group items into variables but when I do so I get the error: Not enough arguments for mixin.

```
$MainColor: 1, 2, 3;

@mixin _testColor($one, $two, $three) {
      // something
}

.Test{
    &.Again{
        @include _testColor($MainColor); // here it says I don't have enough arguments
    }
 }
```

Comment: Would need to see what your mixin is trying to do but that would be expected since `$MainColor` would count as one var (a sass list) passed to something expecting `$one, $two, $three` which unfortunately you can't pass in such a way you would hope like maybe `@include _testColor(@each $color in $MainColor{$color})`, lists don't work that way sorry amigo.

Comment: ok thanks for the information